# entity framework-relationship, datatype enum required primary key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i am new to entity framework. i am trying to create a database by entity framework. And I can't solve it. can you see my code and help me. I'm using asp.net core web app (mvc),  framework current is 7.0. Thank.

```
public class Product
    {
        [ForeignKey("Supplier")]
        public string SupplierId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public Supplier? Supplier { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public string ProductId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Product Name is required"),
            MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "too short")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int Quantity { get; set; } = 0;
        public double Price { get; set; } = 0;
        public Category Category { get; set; }
        public StateOfProduct State { get; set; }
        public DateTime DayOfManufacture { get; set; } = DateTime.Now; // thời gian xuất xưởng
        //public string ProductImage { get; set; } //chỉ có 1 ảnh 
        public List<Image> ProductImage { get; set; } = new List<Image>(); //chứa nhiều ảnh
        public string Info { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Describe { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    }
```

```
public class Category
    {
        enum CategoryMethod
        {
            Phone,
            Laptop,
            Tablets, //máy tính bảng
            SmartWatch, //đồng hồ thông minh
            Earphone, //tai nghe
            Camera,
            Houseware,//gia dụng
            Accessory,//phụ kiện
            Television,
        }
    }
```

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvH5Y.png)
```

i am trying to create database by entity framework and through it create database in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Define a primary key for the Category class.*

Here's the modified code: (Added few more classes)

```
public class Product
{
    [ForeignKey("Supplier")]
    public string SupplierId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Supplier? Supplier { get; set; }
    
    [Key]
    public string ProductId { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name is required")]
    [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Too short")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
    public int Quantity { get; set; } = 0;
    public double Price { get; set; } = 0;
    
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    
    public StateOfProduct State { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime DayOfManufacture { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    
    // Use ICollection<ProductImage> instead of List<Image>
    public ICollection<ProductImage> ProductImage { get; set; } = new List<ProductImage>();
    
    public string Info { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Describe { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class Category
{
    [Key] // Define a primary key for the Category class
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    
    public CategoryMethod Method { get; set; }
}

public enum CategoryMethod
{
    Phone,
    Laptop,
    Tablets,
    SmartWatch,
    Earphone,
    Camera,
    Houseware,
    Accessory,
    Television
}

public class ProductImage
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    // Add properties specific to the image, such as ImageUrl, ImagePath, etc.
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    // ... other properties
}
```